# How to rename files to monotonically incrementing sequence numbers followed by a suffix?

Tags: bash, find, exec

I want to rename all files under a particular directory to a number followed by a suffix. For example, I want to rename all *.jpg files to 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, ...

I thought about using `find` for this (something like `find ./*.jpg --exec mv {} <number_of_iteration>.jpg`) but I don't know what I would put in as `<number_of_iteration>`.

Can I use `find` to do this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Hi Gabrijel. I changed your question to focus on the problem that you seem to want to solve, rather than on your proposed solution which may or may not be the best way to do it. If you feel that in doing so I changed your intent, feel free to either **[edit] further** (recommended) or roll back the edit entirely (click the "edited ... ago" link above my name, and click "rollback" above the revision you want to roll back to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to maintain the iteration separately. For example, use a script `move_count` containing the following:-

```
[ -w ~/MoveCount ] || echo 0 >~/MoveCount
read count <~/MoveCount
((++count))
echo $count >~/MoveCount
mv "$1" "$count.${1##*.}"
```

Then your `find` command would become:

```
find -iname "*.jpg" -exec bash -c "move_count {}" \;
```

Note that `bash` is called explicitly because the default `sh` doesn't understand some of the syntax I have used. Alternatively, make `#!/bin/bash` the first line of `move_count`.

Comment: Couldn't you just as easily simply put `#!/bin/bash` at the top and do away with the `bash -c` in `-exec`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I got used to using `bash -c` after I previously had another problem with using `find -exec` with a batch file. I can't quite remember the details, but it may have been to do with where parameters were expanded, and that doesn't apply here.

Comment: I have updated my answer, and removed `.jpg` from the `move_count` call: my first draft used the second parameter as the extension, but I then changed it to extract the extension from the first parameter, as this maintains the original case.